# Get rid of fragments

Tags: android

I decided to not use fragments for now, although Android wants developers to now use it. 
But I don't find it useful at the beginning. Unfortunately my IDE prepares everything to use fragments, so my question basically is, how to I get rid of everything, thats necessary for fragments? Is there a way to create a project without fragments? Thats what I did:

```
package com.pthuermer.juraquiz;

import java.io.IOException;

// import com.pthuermer.juraquiz.QuizActivity.PlaceholderFragment; // only necessary for     Fragments

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

public class AppLaunch extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_launch);

    /* FRAGMENTS
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    } 
    END FRAGMENTS */

    // code goes here...

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.app_launch, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 * Useredit: not going to use fragments for now.

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_launch,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
*/

}
```

Comment: Not really a question. What is the task at hand? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AndyFaizan I understood the question, read it completely then you will get to know what OP want to do.

Comment: I don't know why guys keeping downvote this question

Comment: I don't know either. Pretty stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think many people in the Android community will agree that fragments are not easy to handle and even draw new problems, some of them without even a decent proper solution.

Nevertheless, trying to remove all fragments from an app is not an easy task and might require good Android programming skills. You will have to convert your fragments either to views or activities, and that is not so easy to do, especially for activities containing multiple fragments.

The best option so far is to use [mortar](https://github.com/square/mortar) from Square, but this alternative is not totally ready and mature yet and using it requires, TMHO, advanced Android skills.

So, if I were a relatively new programmer in the Android world, I would keep fragments, get used to them, understand how they can be used to create reusable components and make apps that work on both phones and tablets.

After a while, when you will master them, you will find their drawbacks, and be able to look for alternatives.

Comment: I have not yet set up an Application. I'm talking about getting rid of them in the very beginning. Like delete every line of code that refers to fragments, then start programming my app.

Comment: So what you did up to now is good. Just put everything in the layout file of your fragment inside your activity's layout. That should more or less work.

Comment: but what you mentioned above... is it suggested to use fragments for phone applications as well?

Comment: @user3385402, I don't see so many applications that can be written only for phones, you would cut out your userbase in most cases. But even for a phone only app, yes, I believe it helps to use fragments from scratch as it will prevent a major refactor to introduce fragments when the phone works and you wanna have a tablet app too.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to study mortar from Square three times and still I haven't the slightest idea how to use it. So I went ahead and used Kotlin+Anko, switched all Fragments to Views and I'm more than happy - the code base is three times smaller, no dirty Fragment hacks, no NPEs that view has not been created for unknown reason, etc. Just implement views as follows:

```
class QuestionnaireView(ctx: Context, questions: List<Question>): _LinearLayout {
  init {
    orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    for (question in questions) {
      verticalLayout {
         textView {
           text = question.title
         }.lparams(matchParent, wrapContent)
         ... etc - generate answer fields as necessary
      }.lparams(matchParent, wrapContent)
    }
  }
}
```

Advantages:

1. Pass parameters using constructors like a human being, not via retarded arguments Bundle
2. No longer worry about the Fragment lifecycle and whether onCreateView() has yet been called or not.
3. Gets rid of exceptions thrown in Android's moveToState() mammoth method
4. Get rid of thousands layout.xml files stored in a single directory
5. Get rid of that styles.xml horrible mess
6. No need to define multiple layouts just to show a list+details on 720dp devices: just add `if(screenWidthDp>=720) { detailView {} }` to your init block.

Disadvantages:

1. No layout previews
2. Android Studio will become so slow it's almost useless.
3. You'll need to generate IDs for those views, otherwise their state will be lost on rotate